# how to wrap google oauth authorize callback in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-apps-script, promise

I have taken one of the google nodejs quick start [examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v1/quickstart/nodejs) as a model for how to do oauth, re-written it as a class object so I can include it in my larger project. I can successfully run an apps script api call [scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) and get a valid return value within the class object, but not how to return it to the containing project.

scripts.run containing function looks like this

```
  Goo.prototype.testAuth = function( auth ){
     var script = google.script('v1');
     var cmd = {
        auth,
        resource: { function: 'test_auth', devMode: true },
        scriptId: '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
     };

     script.scripts.run(
        cmd,
        function( err, resp ){
        if( err ){ console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);return }
        if( resp.error ){console.log('Script error message: '
                             + resp.error.details[0].error.errorMessage);}
        else {
           console.log('resp from api call', resp.response.result );
           return resp.response.result ;
        }
     });

  };
```

with the **return resp.response.result** 
 being the problematic part because it does not passed back to **var response** in the container

```
 var Goo = require('./Goo.js');
 var goo = new Goo();
 var response = goo.test_auth();
 console.log('response to use elsewhere ',response);
```

as those in the know know, the console.log in the Goo class returns a value while the console.log in the container returns undefined.

All the Goo class is wrapped up like this if that's important

```
  (function(){
     var Goo = (function(){
        var Goo = function(config){
        }
        Goo.prototype.test_auth = function(){
            this.authorize( this.testAuth );
        };
        Goo.prototype.testAuth = function(){};
        Goo.prototype.authorize = function(){};
     })();
     module.exports = Goo;
  })();
```

How should I structure this to return a value to be used in the container?

I'm not clear if I should be trying to wrap script.scripts.run in a promise, if it is already returning a promise and I don't know how to await it's return, or if the fact that I'm dealing with a callback function makes that the wrong solution. Any guidance here is appreciated.

I'm using node.js and googleapis ^24.0.0

Comment: Thanks @danh that did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `testAuth` function doesn't return anything as currently written.  One could "promisify" it something like the following...

```
Goo.prototype.testAuth = function( auth ){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var script = google.script('v1');
        var cmd = {
           auth,
           resource: { function: 'test_auth', devMode: true },
           scriptId: '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
        };

        script.scripts.run(
           cmd,
           function( err, resp ){
           if( err ){
               console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
               reject(err);
           } else if( resp.error ){
               console.log('Script error message: ' + resp.error.details[0].error.errorMessage);
               reject(resp.error);
           } else {
               console.log('resp from api call', resp.response.result );
               resolve(resp.response.result);
           }
        });
    });
};
```

Then call it like this...

```
var Goo = require('./Goo.js');
var goo = new Goo();
goo.test_auth().then(response => {
    console.log('response to use elsewhere ',response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('error ',error);
});
```

Sorry indentation formatting is a little strange.  The OP uses 3 spaces for indents, rather than the usual 2 or 4.  (Note to self:  idea for the next episode of "Silicon Valley")